# python : Find a skipped value in an array during a while loop

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a while loop that runs through a fixed step and constantly checks if a value in an array is not equal to the while loop counter, and prints that number:

```
import numpy as np

values = [60.0, 75.8, 85.0, 90.0]
values = np.asarray(values)
counter = 50
while counter <= 100:
    closest = (np.abs(values - counter)).argmin()
    if (values[closest] > (counter - 1) and values[closest] <counter):
        print("we skipped a value " + str(values[closest]))
    counter = counter + 1
```

I wrote this code which has the mentioned functionality but it doesn't seem very elegant or efficient. Is there a quicker way to find these skipped values in Python?

Comment: It seems like you are just checking if the number is a whole number, no? And if it is inside the range of [50, 100]?

Comment: No , if the values are equal to any of the counter values then we good , if not we skipped one value , the jump between counters could also be 0.1 its a global variable

Comment: Why does your code not need to print that we skipped a value if the counter is equal to 70 for example? 70 would be in the loop counter, but it is not in your array.

Comment: What is your criteria for "skipping" a value? It seems to be just ``counter > values[closest] > counter - 1``, which is only satisfied for numbers that aren't integer values. If you don't want to skip a value, why don't you directly iterate on the values?

Comment: @vladimir_putin then we start from 70 , we only show the skipped values which are with in the loop counter

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes if the loop jump is one but lets say the jump is 0.5 and we have a value 70.78 we will still skip it

Comment: It doesn’t really matter whether you are looking for multiples of 1 (integers) or something else. Point is, you can calculate this easily (e.g. using modulo). The question is *what is your goal* that a better solution must still satisfy? Do you just want to find the indices (i.e. can we just calculate them)? Do you want to do something (i.e. do you need the loop)? Do you want to do something with the values (i.e. do you need another kind of loop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This avoids looping and prints a list of skipped values:

```
print("skipped values: " + str(values[np.isin(values, range(50, 101), invert=True)]))
```

`numpy.isin` returns values from the first argument that are in the second argument.  Setting `invert` to `True` means return everything not in the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from the question exactly what you need, but this produces the same output:

```
for v in sorted(set(values).difference(range(50, 101))):
    print("we skipped a value " + str(v))
```

It creates a `set` from the `values`, removes every element between `50` and `100` inclusive, then prints any remaining values in ascending order.